# Where can I upload videos to link to from the 'src' attribute of a HTML5 <video> tag?

Tags: html, video, google-drive-api, dropbox

I've uploaded my video on Google Drive and Dropbox and tried to give the 'src' attribute the url copied from these platforms but the video doesn't show up.
Seems like that url doesn't link up to very final video element but only to an upper level that the  tag source attribute doesn't accept.

I'm asking as I don't have my local environment where to upload the video (don't ask me why) so I'd really need to upload it somewhere remote I can successfully link to from inside the  tag.
In alternative, if you know a way to make a video hosted on Google Drive and Dropbox to show up via  tag, I'd be happy with that one too.
Thank you!

Comment: Please copy your code in here for us to see. 

Comment: Google drive is not a file hosting service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I've realised that gDrive or Dropbox are not made for the purpose I had in mind, so I guess I'll pay for a hosting platform or find some other solution.
Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you want.
Here is a place for you to go: [hubspot.com's list of *video* hosting sites](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/video-hosting-sites).
And [SproutVideo](https://sproutvideo.com/?utm_feeditemid=&utm_device=c&utm_term=video%20hosting%20services&utm_source=google&utm_medium=ppc&utm_campaign=Hosting&hsa_cam=15311963015&hsa_grp=129504024706&hsa_mt=p&hsa_src=g&hsa_ad=562818908831&hsa_acc=6976756125&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_kw=video%20hosting%20services&hsa_tgt=kwd-429894079&hsa_ver=3&gclid=CjwKCAiApvebBhAvEiwAe7mHSEKnB3VONNIVQcxYg1YFslPKAqae4QVmEB-Q5QvxcwBKEwZjxHihFhoCMWUQAvD_BwE) or [Muse.ai](https://muse.ai/?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=cheap_hosting&gclid=CjwKCAiApvebBhAvEiwAe7mHSAW-aVJvuUVe9rdz28mVUPP-DR-rRab9gTYqS_IVIcCtmy_wBoDFwxoCl_8QAvD_BwE) might be the better ones.

And as a bonus, in case you ever need it (for images):
Here is a good place for you to go: [lifewire.com's top free *image* hosting websites](https://www.lifewire.com/top-free-image-hosting-websites-1357014).
And I recommend [imgur](https://imgur.com/) personally.

Comment: Thank you. I now realise what I wanted to achieve is not a given, gdrive and dropbox are not hosting services  ‍♂️, like someone said in the comments...
Thank you for your advice, though these you have to pay for, I wanted free (I know, cheap...) - I'm at peace now...

Comment: Sure, I get it. I don't use any of those anymore.  Sorry I couldn't find better.